# C++ substring returning wrong results

Tags: c++, substring

I have this string:

```
std::string date = "20121020";
```

I'm doing:

```
std::cout << "** Date: " << date << "\n";
std::cout << "Year: " << date.substr(0,4) << "\n";
std::cout << "Month: " << date.substr(4,6) << "\n";
std::cout << "Day: " << date.substr(6,8) << "\n";
```

But im getting:

```
** Date: 20121020
Year: 2012
Month: 1020
Day: 20
```

Notice that month should be `10`, not `1020`. Positions are correct, tried everything, that is it failing?

Comment: Second argument is length of substring, not end index.

Comment: `std::string date = 20121020` is syntactically incorrect.  Did you mean `std::string date = "20121020"`?

Comment: @DanielFischer, might as well make that an answer, because that's exactly the problem.

Comment: @JohnDibling, sorry, miss the qoutes when writing to OS :)

Comment: Engineering is about knowing, not guessing. Read the documentation. And if you insist on guessing and your code doesn't work right, read the documentation.

Comment: Java programmer trying to code in C++ comes to this question :P

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
std::cout << "Month: " << date.substr(4,6) << "\n";
```

The second argument is wrong.  You are specifying, "Give me as substring of *6* characters, starting at position 4."

You probably want:

```
std::cout << "Month: " << date.substr(4,2) << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I thought that substr will be like Python slice, and you have to pas the positions :) Thanks again

Comment: It's different from most other languages. Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
std::cout << "** Date: " << date << "\n";
std::cout << "Year: " << date.substr(0,4) << "\n";
std::cout << "Month: " << date.substr(4,2) << "\n";
std::cout << "Day: " << date.substr(6,2) << "\n";
```

I believe substr takes start and **length** as arguments.

Comment: That was the mistake, I thought that substr syntax will be like python slicing, and the args where both positions of the string, Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

string substr ( size_t pos = 0, size_t n = npos ) const;

pos
Position of a character in the current string object to be used as starting character for the substring.
If the position passed is past the end of the string, an out_of_range exception is thrown.

n
Length of the substring.
If this value would make the substring to span past the end of the current string content, only those characters until the end of the string are used.
npos is a static member constant value with the greatest possible value for an element of type size_t, therefore, when this value is used, all the characters between pos and the end of the string are used as the initialization substring.

So your mistake in code is that you have expected that the second parameter to be the position of the last char instead of the length of the substring.

Comment: If you quote documentation, please quote en.cppreference.com instead of cplusplus.com. the latter has known inconsistencies and wrong information

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Anyway for this situation I've checked the information and I found that is right, from my point of view is not really relevant the surse of information as long as the information is corect. Ontop of this on site specified by you the explanation is shorter which is not always a good thing when you want to explain something to somebody else.