# Why Is string::substr Misbehaving?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, gcc, substr

Given this code:

```
auto str = "a,b,c"s;
vector<string> tokens;
string::size_type start = -1;
string::size_type finish = str.find(',');

do {
    tokens.push_back(str.substr(start + 1, finish));
    start = finish;
    finish = str.find(',', start + 1);
} while (start != string::npos);
```

I would expect `tokens` to contain:

1. "a"
2. "b"
3. "c"

When I run the code however I get:

1. "a"
2. "b,c"
3. "c"

I've printed out debug information in this live example: http://ideone.com/fx3uC9

Is this a bug? I see it in gcc and Visual Studio so it seems like it's something I've done wrong.

Comment: This is what a debugger is for. This is a very short, simple, trivial algorithm. Use your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, each time through the loop. Examine the values of all these variables. See what they point to. Read the description of `std::string`'s methods, and what each parameter should be. Figure it out. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: The second argument to `substr()` is a *length*, not an index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of a question asked in a bygone era when questions were upvoted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12827030/2642059

Answer (score 3):

If you read the documentation for [`substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), the signature is:

```
basic_string substr( size_type pos = 0,
                     size_type count = npos ) const;
```

The second argument is not the position of the end (like every other function in `<algorithm>` that takes a range), it's the length of the substring. So where you have `finish` as the end, you instead need `finish - (start + 1)` as the length.

Comment: tl;dr blah blah **read the documentation for substr()** blah blah ;)

Comment: @JonathanWakely It's a pleasant escape from the jungle that is Documentation.